# A minimum configuration or turnkey web-server to run Django or any other python based web-framework?

Tags: python, django, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

Is there anything similar solution like XAMPP (which is php ready) for python frameworks. More or less like a turnkey solution deploy and run python based web-services on linux and windows desktops.
I am confused what is the purpose of Tornado Web Server. The site says it is Web Server, then it also say something about Web Server Framework. As it is written in python, does it perform as well as apache or ngnix?

Comment: Read this: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#running-tornado-in-production

Comment: re: "performance", This depends greatly on the specific applition.  Some workloads will naturally work better in some servers than others, and there's usually at least one use case where each server shines the brightest.  On the other hand, performance tuning should not be your concern when you're looking for a cross platform, turnkey solution, and if performance is your main concern, no turnkey solution will be ideal for your specific application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using nginx + CherryPy http://www.cherrypy.org/ quite happily.  CherryPy seems about as simple as it can get when hosting a Django powered website.

Answer (score 0):

You will always deploy some kind of web server as a front-end to your Python code.

Apache, nginx or lighttpd.

For most Python frameworks, you'll use mod_wsgi.

For other Python frameworks (like Tornado), you won't use mod_wsgi.

Each Python framework is unique, so there's no single, standard answer.

Since you mention Django specifically in the tags, you'll generally use use Apache and mod_wsgi.  You'll read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

You won't use Tornado.

Comment: mod_wsgi == apache, but wsgi == pep333 == portable python webapps.  LOTS of web servers can host wsgi apps, apache can do so via mod_wsgi (and there are a few other options).  wsgi to fastcgi wrappers exist to support even more http servers, http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Servers